# Android: transform image using a Matrix

Tags: android

I'm looking to transform an image using a Matrix on the onDraw method of a custom class I created which extends ImageView e.g.,

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.setMatrix(imageMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)mIcon).getBitmap(), imageMatrix, null);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

However, what I coded above does not really work. How exactly do I apply the imageMatrix on the canvas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `Drawable.draw(Canvas)` method:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.setMatrix(imageMatrix);
    ((BitmapDrawable)mIcon).draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All you did is good, just put the super call to be the last, coz there is where all the painting is done...

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.setMatrix(imageMatrix);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```